# Insufficient prvileges for Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to revoke the refresh tokens of a specific user (my own) in AzureAD to force a completely new logon to an applicaiton.

As there is no UI option for this in the Azure Portal (there actually is -> see in one of the anwers) I am using the 'Windows Terminal's 'Azure Cloud Shell' option as follows directly from the built-in Azure Cloud shell:

```
Connect-AzureAD

PS /home/...> Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken -ObjectId "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

The GUID I pass in the parameteter is the object ID of my user.
Unfortunately this fails due to a permission issue:

```
Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken: Error occurred while executing RevokeUserAllRefreshTokens
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Access to invalidate refresh tokens operation is denied.
RequestId: fd5f5256-3909-46af-b709-8068e0744f25
DateTimeStamp: Mon, 09 Aug 2021 16:56:28 GMT
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
```

If I try to execute the same in the Cloud Shell within the azure portal, the result is the same.

If I use a 'classic' PowerShell, then it works. So apparently something is missing with the authentication of the Cloud Shell.
When I log in I get to select the right tenant, and my read access e.g. to the user list works perfectly.

I have no more clues what I would be missing:

- I am Owner of the subscription in the azure role assignments
- I do have the Global Administrator role assigned in AzureAD

Is there some special command to 'elevate' the permissions?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the issue on my Azure AD tenant , but unfortunately I didn’t receive the error you are getting .

[image]

**Note:** Make sure you connect with AD with your Global Admin account `i.e. admin@domainname.onmicrosoft.com or username_outlook.com#EXT#@domainname.onmicrosoft.com`, so that you see the correct details in every column in the above red box.

[image]

**Other options :**

- From Portal you can go to the user profile and click on revoke
  sessions .

[image]

- Using [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) you can revoke signin Sessions.

  Post https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0//users/UserObjectID/revokeSignInSessions

[image]

**Reference:**
[user: revokeSignInSessions - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-revokesigninsessions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Thank you AnsumanBal-MT for the detailed answer. The "Revoke Sessions" button is a very good hint, I did not notice it so far, as I was so much focused on getting the CLI working. Logging in with the same admin user pressing this button was successful - so my user seems to have the permissions.

Comment: Coming back to the terminal based access, when executing Connect-AzureAD in my case it does not give any output. Also if I try LogLevel info it does not write any log file, and using the Confirm option also did not give any prompt. I was trying this command in the azure portal's buil-in cloud shall, as well as with Windows Terminal's 'Azure Cloud Shell' option.
I now installed the AzureAD cmdlet package fore classic PowerShell and use it there -> there I do get the expected output and also log files.
I can confirm that that the logon users is correct, and the revoke works from there.

Comment: Glad to hear it that it worked ! yes you are correct i have provided it for AzureAD cmdlet for classic powershell ..